# How to open a link not in the app? Ionic vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I am developing an application on ionic vue. Some content comes from the api. This content may contain a link <a href="...

How do I open such links on another tab?

As an option, I can analyze the content and replace the links with window.open, but it seems wrong to me.

Perhaps there are other practices for this. But I didn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

Ups, in the android app it's work fine. Opened browser. My fault.